# How can we open excel addin taskpane open by default when excel loads

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

Currently I am working on a requirement where I am creating one excel add-in which loads some default data in excel in a specific name range which I am able to achieve it. But to execute that code I have to manually click and open task pane.

To avoid this I tried below approach by which task pane is loading but first time I have to open it manually as settings need to save in first time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

manifest.xml

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
</Action>
```

Then in Home.js

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

Any idea where I should put this code so task pane can open without user interaction on first time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have built your Add-in with the yo template, or at least followed that pattern then you'll want to drop that code in taskpane.js or equivalent.

Comment: I have created it using visual studio approach. Where I have web project and one manifest project .

Comment: Presumably you have a taskpane.js or equivalent in that case?